# Why was this answer turned into a comment?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

This question is about what a government can do to avoid the wealthy from imposing their will through physical violence: [How to regulate the expected result of fights between hired mercenaries?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/143036/21222)

I have [answered](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/143047/21222) that by switching to a certain form of government (and socioeconomical organization), the problem would be averted altogether. [However, my answer was deleted and turned into a comment](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/59118).

I understand that it made it into the queue because somebody didn't think it was fit for the question. However, it was not my intention to comment; the format of the post wasn't even fit for a comment.

I posted what I posted because I think I have a valid answer to the question. I think the appropriate action when you think an answer is bad is to downvote it. I have no problem with that.

Can someone explain to me why, in a question about what a government can do to prevent an economic maneuver, an answer suggesting a change in the form of government is invalid?

Comment: I'm not certain why it was turned into a comment, but it's a very poor answer. The premise of the question included the ability to hire mercenaries to fit a requirement, and that the guild must act to "ensure its own profits." Further the answer seems low quality, far lower quality than, say, this meta question. However all of that makes your answer fitting for a downvote, in my opinion, not a comment. I'd be for reversing this action.

Comment: @NexTerren yeah. It's far from being my best answer indeed. But for what is worth, I see it as a frame challenge. Had I the opportunity to edit it, I would address the points you've raised. Thanks!

Comment: Also, rereading my comment, I think it might it come across as pretty harsh. Sorry if it read such.

Answer (score 1):

I am not the moderator who turned that answer in a comment. Howvere, here are my 2 cents: if those lines contain an answer, it is so hidden between them that it would require an additional question to pull it out. Long story short, as it stands it is a poor answer.

Since we generally prefer answers which address and explain the point asked by the OP, that aspect was clearly missing.

I can understand the attempt to give a witty answer that catches the eyes (and the votes) of part of the audience, but since we don't put a limit on the number of characters which can be typed in an answer, I think it would have greatly helped to use those very lines as tag line, followed by a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I don't disagree with anything you said, but it still doesn't explain why it's not just a poor quality answer (thus warranting a downvote), but instead was turned into a comment.

Comment: @NexTerren, low quality answers entering the low quality queue can be deleted with a sufficient number of votes (thus it's not just a downvote), or turned into a comment if they somehow comment the question instead of answering it.